Custom accessibility VoiceOver identifier on ActionSheet in SwiftUI is not working
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingConfirmationDialog = false
    @State private var options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Options") {
            showingConfirmationDialog = true
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Choose an Option", isPresented: $showingConfirmationDialog, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Button(option) {
                    print("\(option) selected")
                }
                .accessibilityLabel(option)           // Ensure VoiceOver reads the title
                .accessibilityTraits([.isLink])       // Mark it as a link
                .accessibilityRemoveTraits([.isButton])
            }
            
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                print("Cancel selected")
            }
            .accessibilityLabel("Cancel the action")
        }
    }
}

Using confirmationDialog(:)
Want to read confirmationDialog button as link but its reading as button.
Any possible way to change it?
